# How to get source branch name in Azure Build Validation

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, automated-tests

So I'm trying my hands out on Azure Pipelines, and I'm looking at the Build Validation, Here 've specified a pipeline to execute whenever a PR is created using the YAML method.

Now my question is how do I get/grab the name of the source branch so that I can deploy that for validating it against the test cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find a source branch during the build process, you can use the predefined variable `System.PullRequest.SourceBranch` ([System variables (DevOps Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables-devops-services)). How to use variables, you can find here: [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch).